# Ruby on Rails: Active::RecordNotFound Couldn't find Article without an ID

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, activerecord

New to rails.This problem is most likely due to my misconception of how routing works but unsure. My little program is identical to the `Articles` blog example on the Ruby on Rails online beginners guide tutorial.

All I want to do is have a button/link in the `show.html.erb` file that would redirect me to another url, but I need to access the articles ID to access the url, in order to get the `title` from that article object.

in articles_controller.rb I have:

```
def join
  @article = Article.find(params[:id]) --->getting error, cant find Article without ID
  redirect_to(**irrelevant code**))
end
```

in show.html.erb I have:

`<%= link_to "Click here", {method: 'get', :controller => "articles", :action => "join"}`

in routes.db i have:

`get '/articles/join', to: 'articles#join'`

I am getting the error 
 ActiveRecord::RecordNotFound in ArticlesController#join 
Couldn't find Article without an ID

Why doesn't this work for my join method? why is id from params[:id] only extractable in the other CRUD operations?

thanks

Comment: You seem to not sending the param `id` from your html. How your join method could know what article you want to get ? So your `params[:id]` is null. Try to print it and you will see.

Comment: you're right, thanks!!

Comment: You could also change your route to `get '/articles/:id/join', to: 'articles#join'` which makes sure an id is required in the path itself.

Answer (score 1):

Because your `join` method require an article id. You need to pass an article in `link_to`

Answer (score 0):

You might be better off using resources syntax in your routes when adding a new action to your controller:

try:

```
resources :articles do
  member do
    get 'join'
  end
end
```

which will give you the extra route:

```
join_article  GET  /articles/:id/join(.format)
```

so you can then use:

```
<%= link_to 'Click Here', join_article(@article) %>
```

in your views.

Answer (score 0):

In your example you need to pass `:id` of the article in the link which is sending your request to action `join` - currently missing parameter.

```
<%= link_to "Click here", {method: 'get', :controller => "articles", :action => "join", :id => @article.id } %>
```

That should set :id and make it accessible in the `articles#join` action.

Answer (score 0):

```
<%= link_to "Click here", {method: 'get', :controller => "articles", :action => "join", id => @article.id} -%>

get '/articles/join/:id', to: 'articles#join'
```